# Which Visual Studio to develop Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Since I cannt register Visual Express 2010 for Windows Phone anymore because Microsoft doesn't support it anymore, which Visual Studio I can do it. Is it still possible?

While I am opening my VS Express there is MessegeBox (You have to regiester it for free). When I open the link there is a sign" Page is not avaible anymore".

I have acces to DreamSpark because I am a student. I just want to finish my Windows Phone 7.1 project but now I dont know how to do it.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just download the [2013 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) and upgrade your project to Windows Phone 8.1 ?

Comment: At the moment I am downloading Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, is it ok also ?

Comment: @miechooy yes, it's ok!

Comment: There is no template for Windows Phone, what can I do ?

Comment: @miechooy open your project, right click > upgrade to windows phone 8-8.1. Why do you want to continue with 7.1 ;

And if this still doesn't work, just create a new project, copy classes / assets and continue development.